# Drupal 7 separate field collection in view

Tags: drupal-7

I have a field collection "user_card" composed of 2 fields: card_name and card_digits.

Right now the field collection is shown like this

```
+---------+---------------------------+
| User id |      title user_card      |
+---------+---------------------------+
|       1 | card_name_1 card_digits_1 |
|       2 | card_name_2 card_digits_2 |
+---------+---------------------------+
```

I need to show in a view that field collection but in 2 different columns, like this.

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+
| User id |  Card name   |  Card digits  |
+---------+--------------+---------------+
|       1 | card_name_1  | card_digits_1 |
|       2 | card_name_2  | card_digits_2 |
+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

Is there a way to do it? or at least have a mecanism to break the collection in 2 separate fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Field Collection Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module.

This module provides a formatter leveraging views for the Field Collection module.

**Usage**

1. After install this module,then you could goto host entity's fields
   display settings page,such as
   admin/structure/profiles/manage/resume/display.
2. at display settings page, you could choose format for you collection
   field,This module provide a new option"Views field-collection items"
3. then at format summary area, you will see "Embed View:
   field_collection_view, default", Yes ,this module using
   views_embed_view function,That mean you need config the name and
   display id of the view you want to use.
4. Now if you visit a page of host entity, you could only see three
   fields," Field collection Item id", "Edit", "Delete",At the bottom
   there is a "Add" link.This is not a bug, that because i do not know
   which fields that added to collection field.
5. Clone views "field_collection_view", at the clone view, you need add
   more fields to it, change the sort criteria,Please do not change the
   existing fields (except "Exclude from display " for
   "Field-collection item: Field-collection item ID"),the Contextual
   filters of " Field-collection item: Field-collection item ID"
6. After that you need config the name /display id of the views you
   want to use at display settings page, such as
   admin/structure/profiles/manage/resume/display,you click the button
   at the right place, then there will be a form inlude 2
   elements,"name" and "display id".